# Push Data from a WCF Service to Website

Tags: wcf, signalr

I have the following scenario, and I would like to know if there is a solution to achieve such thing:

I have a WCF service that is running in a backend server, and it does bulk data processing, like inserting records into DB, and I would like to have this service send a message or notification once a record has done processing to a webpage (ASP.NET Page), where this page should be listening to these messages and display a progress with the finished tasks at real-time.

**Note:** The WCF service is separate from the webpage; This means that the WCF service process starts when another WCF service calls it in the backend server, so the web-page should only 'listen' to the updates that comes from WCF service.

Through my research, I have come up with SignalR, can this technology help me build a solution for such a scenario, or maybe there is some other way to achieve it?

Comment: Sounds like a service bus would be a good solution, check out nServicebus

Comment: @hugh XSockets seems to be what I am looking for. I will mark Uffe's answer as the correct one. Many thanks to all of you for the great information. :)