# how to trigger mvc application when a request is made to wcf service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, events, triggers

I have a wcf service that receives xml and saves data to database. Then I have mvc application that shows data from the same database that wcf stores data in. How can I connect wcf and mvc application so that each time that data is stored to database, mvc web page is refreshed with new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Calvin says SignalR is one option. Another option is XSockets.NET see previous similar question [Push Data from a WCF Service to Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265609/push-data-from-a-wcf-service-to-website)

There is a comparison table between XSockets and a SignalR here http://xsockets.net/xsockets-vs-signalr . Use the one that feels best for you, I'm just providing options.

If neither alternative feels good you can also look at superwebsocket and fleck.

I would def go for websockets in your case.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how to do that. If your application will allow this. One of the solution what I like is to use *SqlDependency* (or *SqlCacheDependency* if you cache these items)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look at implementing SignalR (http://signalr.net) to push notifications from the Server to the Client.