# WCF callback in HTML5 client

Tags: javascript, html, wcf

I implemented a WCF service, but I need to send data to HTML5 client when it's available in the server side, now the question is:
Is it possible to implement Windows Communication Service callbacks in HTML 5 client?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the same problem, but you should check the question at [Push Data from a WCF Service to Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265609/push-data-from-a-wcf-service-to-website)

Also, check SignalR (http://signalr.net/) and XSockets (http://xsockets.net/api/guides/boosting-a-wcf-to-realtime)